# I want to run my sql commands using .bat file

Tags: windows, teradata

I am using Teradata. I know that bteq scripts have to be used. Can any one tell me exactly how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't **have** to use BTEQ scripts, it's just the common way to submit command line scripts to Teradata.

When you talk about *.bat* you probably work with Windows, but that dosn't matter, there's BTEQ for Windows and different flavours of Mainfram/Unix/Linux system.

Calling a BTEQ scritp is similar to any other script you use, in your batch file you enter:

```
BTEQ < myscript.txt
```

myscript.txt contains BTEQ and SQL commands like

```
.logon system/user,password;
insert into tab select * from tab2;
.quit
```

Check the BTEQ manual for details of the BTEQ available commands:

http://www.info.teradata.com/edownload.cfm?itemid=130420006